# vba sort loop requires rank

Tags: vba, loops, sorting, rank

I have a spreadsheet that has student test scores  from each week.It has 5 fields,name(column A),year(column B),level(column C),week(columnD) and score(ColE).Each student have their own block on the sheet and each block of rows is seperated by and empty row.The blocks of rows will vary in size.(please see below).
I have code that will order the score(column E) from highest to lowest,(see before sort and after sort)
What I would like to do is to insert another column between the week column and the score column that gives the position of each score after the sort,and it would appear as it is in Fig 3 below .I think it would require some sort of RANK procedure and a loop.Notice also that some times the scores by a student for certain weeks can be the same so then there will be a joint top(or second or third etc)as with John Ellis joint 4th with two sets of 54 and phil simm who has a joint 1st and 4th.
Hope this makes sense.Any help much appreciated
At the bottom the spreadshhet figures I have also placed the code that I used for looping and sorting column E the score column.

```
BEFORE SORT(Fig1)                   
name       year     level   week    score   
jill evans  5         2      10       56    
jill evans  5         2      11       49    
jill evans  5         2      12       77    
jill evans  5         2      13      84 
empty   empty   empty   empty   empty   
john ellis  3   4   10  45  
john ellis  3   4   11  54  
john ellis  3   4   12  54  
john ellis  3   4   13  29  
john ellis  3   4   14  66  
empty   empty   empty   empty   empty   
phil simm   4   6   10  89  
phil simm   4   6   11  76  
phil simm   4   6   12  41  
phil simm   4   6   13  41  
phil simm   4   6   14  56  
phil simm   4   6   15  59  
phil simm   4   6   16  61  
phil simm   4   6   17  61  




AFTER SORT(Fig2)                    

name        year    level   week        score
jill evans  5        2       11         49
jill evans  5        2       10         56
jill evans  5        2       12         77
jill evans  5        2       13         84
empty   empty   empty   empty       empty
john ellis  3   4   13      29
john ellis  3   4   10      45
john ellis  3   4   11      54
john ellis  3   4   12      54
john ellis  3   4   14      66
empty   empty   empty   empty       empty
phil simm   4   6   12      41
phil simm   4   6   13      41
phil simm   4   6   14      56
phil simm   4   6   15      59
phil simm   4   6   16      61
phil simm   4   6   17      61
phil simm   4   6   11      76
phil simm   4   6   10      89

    FIG3 with the position row included between week col and score       col                    
name          year  level   week    position    score
jill evans       5   2       11         1       49
jill evans       5   2       10         2       56
jill evans       5   2       12         3       77
jill evans       5   2       13         4       84
empty   empty   empty   empty   empty   empty
john ellis  3   4   13  1   29
john ellis  3   4   10  2   45
john ellis  3   4   11  3   54
john ellis  3   4   12  3   54
john ellis  3   4   14  4   66
empty   empty   empty   empty   empty   empty
phil simm   4   6   12  1   41
phil simm   4   6   13  1   41
phil simm   4   6   14  2   56
phil simm   4   6   15  3   59
phil simm   4   6   16  4   61
phil simm   4   6   17  4   61
phil simm   4   6   11  5   76
phil simm   4   6   10  6   89
```

So the position column reflects the new position of the score after the sort.
If two scores are the same then that will be a joint position,as with John Ellis joint 4th with two sets of 54 and phil simm who has a joint 1st and 4th.
Hope this nakes sense.Any help much appreciated

```
Sub sortone()                   

Application.ScreenUpdating = False                  
Dim Area As Range, sr As Long, er As Long                   
For Each Area In Range("A2", Range("E" &   Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas                   
  With Area                 
    sr = .Row                   
    er = sr + .Rows.Count - 1                   
    Range("A" & sr & ":E" & er).Sort key1:=Range("E" & sr),   order1:=1                 
  End With                  
Next Area                   
Application.ScreenUpdating = True                   
End Sub
```

many thanks

Comment: do you know about the existing `RANK` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub sortone()
    Dim Area As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .Columns(5).Insert
        .Cells(1, 5).Value = "position"

        For Each Area In .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas
            With Area
                .Resize(, 6).Sort key1:=.Range("F1"), order1:=1
                .Offset(, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=RANK(RC[1]," & .Offset(, 5).Resize(, 1).Address(, , xlR1C1) & ",1)"
            End With
        Next Area
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi DisplayName,
thankyou for that,but what it does is rank the entire sheet ie all the students on the sheet are ranked together.What I am searching for is code that ranks each individual student within their own block.
So the first student is sorted and ranked(by the sort column) and once completed the next student and so on.If you look at Fig 3 of my question you will see what I am trying to do.Many thanks Grey

Comment: yes,it dropped the empty lines to the bottom then ranked all the students from top to bottom,so john ellis was at the top with 89 and john eliis bottom with 29 Thanks Grey

Comment: I tested it with data as per your examples, i.e.: 5 columns initially in place (name, year, level, week, score) from A to E; student "blocks" starting from row 2 and separated by blank lines.  It ends leaving blank lines where they are, ordering each "block" separately by ascending score which is shifted to column F whiile column E is filled with "relative" ranks (i.e. within each "block")

Comment: @greycat, delete the answer you just posted, since it's not an answer at all! And if you want to go on with my code, please give feedbacks about what I wrote: is your data layout as I described it?

Answer (score 1):

### "RankIf" conditional rank by Subsets using `SUMPRODUCT`:

An alternate way to rank, kind of like if there were a `RANKIF` function, uses `SUMPRODUCT` to do conditional ranks:

[image: rankif]

**Formula in `D5`:**

```
=1+SUMPRODUCT((A$4:A$21=A5)*($B$4:$B$21>B5))
```

...the absolute/relative cells references are setup to allow the formula to be copied or filled down & right.

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [SUMPRODUCT Function (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)
- Office.com : [RANK Function (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rank-function-6a2fc49d-1831-4a03-9d8c-c279cf99f723)
- MSDN : [WorksheetFunction.Rank Method (VBA/Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-rank-method-excel)
- Office.com : [Excel statistical functions: Representing ties by using RANK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/828678/excel-statistical-functions-representing-ties-by-using-rank)

Comment: Hi ashleedawg
Thanks.Yes the rank formula would work,but that would apply to the sheet in its entirety.I am looking to rank each individual student block(please see fig 3 above),I think it may require some sort of loop regards grey

Comment: It will apply to whatever range you specify in the function (but never the "whole sheet")...  you can have a hundred different set of data being ranked on the same worksheet if you want.

Comment: but the blocks of student rows are not given range names,they are just groups of records of varying size seperated by an empty row.I could go through each group and RANK them manually but this would take ages,is there a loop I can use to do this.my attemps so far have failed?

Comment: Give me a few mins for another example

Comment: I would've been quicker but I had to look up the color codes for Gold, Silver & Bronze...  In retrospect, they're pretty ugly, but the purpose is to easier illustrate how it's ranking the groups.

Comment: Hi asleedawg
Many thanks for that,but the only column that I want to rank is the scores column,and then rank  each  student individual as a seperate unit.So first Jill evans scores would be ranked by score in her case 1 to 4,then on to john ellis who is 1 to 5,then on to phil simm who is 1 to 8 and so on

Comment: You're welcome.  What you describe is what I intended but I had a typo (answering multiple questions simultaneously, sorry!)   I (hope) this is what you need.  The double-ups are due to tied scores.  Just a note on your question, if year/level/week are irrelevant, they shouldn't have been included (more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))...

Answer (score 0):

```
name        year    level   week    position    score
john ellis   3        4     13       1           29
phil simm    4        6     12       2           41
phil simm    4        6     13       2           41
john ellis   3        4     10       4           45
jill evans   5        2     11       5          49
john ellis   3        4     11       6           54
john ellis   3        4     12       6           54
jill evans   5        2     10       8           56
phil simm    4        6     14       8           56
phil simm    4        6     15      10           59
phil simm    4        6     16      11          61
phil simm    4        6     17      11           61
john ellis   3        4     14      13           66
phil simm    4        6     11      14           76
jill evans   5        2     12      15           77
jill evans   5        2     13      16           84
phil simm    4        6     10      17           89
empty   empty   empty   empty   #VALUE! empty
empty   empty   empty   empty   #VALUE! empty
```

Comment: Hi the above is how it appeared when I run the code,hope this helps